# How to debug problems on a FRAM communication?

Tags: non-volatile-memory

I have a proprietary device with this [FM25VN10 FRAM](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-FM25V10_1-Mbit_(128_K_8)_Serial_(SPI)_F-RAM-DataSheet-v12_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7d0d8da4017d0ebe03d63127) and, due to shortage, I had to replace a compatible model, which in this case is this one [CY15B004Q](https://pt.mouser.com/datasheet/2/100/CYPR_S_A0011119726_1-2541265.pdf).

However, I am having struggling to have communication and I don't know why:

- The pinout and application circuits are the same from both datasheets;
- The op commands are the same (at least for the most basic action which is read the status register)
- Don't think it is a loose connection because I've tried different CY15B004Q FRAMS on different devices

I simply dont get any answer from the FRAM and without HW/FW changes, if I replace for FM25VN10 it works without any problem.

Screenshots of the electrical behavior:

SCK(Red), Hold(Yellow), SI(Blue) and SO(Green)
[image]

SCK(Yellow), SI(Blue) ,SO(green) and CS(Red) lines.
[image]

So, my questions:

1. What am I doing wrong with the SPI communication to not having any output from FRAM?
2. What can I do to dig into the problem and, at least, have 100% sure that the FRAM are without HW problems?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In this case, the first thing I would do is carefully compare the timing diagrams; there is likely a timing difference.

Comment: @rdtsc, I've checked the timings regarding Hold and CS pin and also regarding SCK and SI. I've also checked SCK frequency and its okay...

Comment: @RicardoGoncalves They are quite different in terms of available FRAM. Did you really only need the smaller size? (I'd like to know before bothering to look any further.)

Comment: @RicardoGoncalves Also, I note that the "speed" isn't the same between the two. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comments. @jonk, yes, i know that the (1) speeds are the differente, but they have a common window and I'm working on that and (2) I also know the sizes are very different, but it works for the basic use cases.

Comment: I also find that the output with op command for rdsr is slightly different. Apparently a 0x00 output is a valid output and, unfortuntely, the same if the op code does not exist.... On other commands I am not able to get the correct output also

Comment: @RicardoGoncalves I guess what I'm saying is that I've NOT had such problems before. I suppose it is because I code things right? But... I can't say that there isn't some other issue in your case. I've used a very wide variety of SPI memory devices on a wide variety of processor targets and it has all "just worked right" when I feel I have coded things correctly. So I'm sure this isn't a device problem -- they just work for me. And I'm sure this isn't a processor problem -- they also just work for me. So it must be a design/coding/understanding problem, I think.